# pstricks-add: arrow on arcs

Tags: arrows, pstricks-add

In `pstricks-add`, the arrow tip `-v` does not rotate if it is put on an arc, while other arrow heads do it.

```
\psarc{->}(0,0){1}{0}{30}
\psarc{-v}(0,0){1}{0}{30}
```

Note that along segments, the tip is rotated: `\psline{-v}(0,0)(1,1)`. Is there a way to let it rotate on arcs?

Comment: It might be [a](http://www.clker.com/cliparts/c/3/b/d/1194985428453820625bug_nicu_buculei_01.svg.med.png).

Comment: the vee arrows are designed for lines not arcs. You can change the arrow inset to get a similiar arrow. However I'll have a look at the code

Answer (score 2):

The idea of infinitesimal segment might help here.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid](2,2)
    \psarc(0,0){2}{0}{30}
    \psline{-v}(2;29.9999)(2;30.0001)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]